# How to get runtime version of an managed assembly

Tags: .net

How to get runtime version of an managed assembly

Which section in ildasm gives me this? Metadata?

Thanks for looking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean which version of the framework it's built against? The manifest will contain an assembly reference like this:

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

That's an assembly targeting .NET v4, for example.

Comment: Thanks. But what does Metadataversion at the top of ildasm output signify? Clr run time? How is this different from link /dump /headers clr data section.

Comment: @user393148: I don't know, to be honest. Possibly the version of the IL format itself?